# jquery setInterval runs only one time

Tags: jquery, setinterval

```
function caroussel() {
    $(".cosm-slider ul").animate({marginLeft: '-400px'}, 1500);
} 

 var carossTrigger = setInterval(function() { caroussel(); },5000);
```

Comment: You are probably looking for `-=400px`

Comment: Looks to me like it should work. Can you make an executable [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thauk you very much you saved my day with that equal sign

Comment: You are very welcome :)

Comment: as you know setInterval runs forever and that's what I want. can you please show me how to make the 1st <li> be attached to last <li>,  then the caroussel will be like turning in an infinte cercle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you solved it. For reference though it may be wise to use `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`. setInterval will repeatedly keep trying no matter what the outcome. So you might tell it to move the slider with a frequency greater than the animation time. Its far better to call the function as a callback of the animation. Example logic being: Once you complete this animation then call this yourself again (after a delay).

This is an ugly example but something like:

```js
(function caroussel() {
    window.i = window.i || 0;
    var $slider = $(".cosm-slider ul");
    var slideCount = $slider.find("li").length;
    if(i++ && i<=slideCount){
      $slider.animate({marginLeft: '-=100%'}, 1500, 
        function(){setTimeout(function(){caroussel()},1000);}
      );
    } else {
      i=1;
      $slider.animate({marginLeft: '0px'}, 500, 
        function(){setTimeout(function(){caroussel()},1000);}
      );
    }
})();
```

```css
ul {width:1000%; list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0}
li {
border:1px solid red;
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;
width:10%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cosm-slider">
<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: as you mentioned setInterval runs forever and that's what I want. can you please show me how to make the 1st <li> be attached to last <li>, then the caroussel will be like turning in an infinte cercle